# Zoom On Google Maps Data Layer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm having troubles centering and zooming on the information in the data layer. I have tried to use the approach suggested here: [stackoverflow question: zoom to geojson polygons bounds in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507044/zoom-to-geojson-polygons-bounds-in-google-maps-api-v3). I still initially zoom into the same spot that he was, some where in the pacific ocean near baker island. I am loading a GeoJson object from the server and it displays correctly. My code:

```
function loadMap () {
    var m = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapProp = { 
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(m, mapProp);

    map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {            
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);

        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

    var geoJsonObject = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [
           {
              type: "Feature",
              properties: {},
              geometry: {
                  type: "MultiPolygon",
                  coordinates: [
                      [[[-86.80795499999999, 36.146389], [-86.80605800006222, 36.14733499995285], [-86.806471, 36.147928], [-86.80836699994975, 36.14697700000941], [-86.80795499999999, 36.146389]]],
                      [[[-86.803842, 36.143921999999996], [-86.803761, 36.144005], [-86.80374600001942, 36.1441770000485], [-86.804918, 36.1458], [-86.805436, 36.145536], [-86.80621699999999, 36.146585], [-86.80755499999131, 36.145895000035935], [-86.807208, 36.145385999999995], [-86.806328, 36.144205], [-86.803842, 36.143921999999996]]]
                  ]
              }
           }
        ]
    };
    map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonObject);
}

function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
    if(geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
    }
}
```

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: What does _your_ geoJSON data look like?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've just edited to include a mock out of the object returned from the server. The polygons get much more complicated than this so I choose a small one. This is the area around a few block in Nashville, TN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your modified `processPoints` routine doesn't handle polygons.

Yours:

```
function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
    if(geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
    }
}
```

From the [referenced answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507044/zoom-to-geojson-polygons-bounds-in-google-maps-api-v3):

```
function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
    if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
    } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
    } else {
        geometry.getArray().forEach(function (g) {
            processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
        });
    }
}
```

**working code snippet:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", loadMap);
var map;

function loadMap() {
  var m = document.getElementById("googleMap");
  var mapProp = {
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(m, mapProp);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
    processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  var geoJsonObject = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [{
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: "MultiPolygon",
        coordinates: [
          [
            [
              [-86.80795499999999, 36.146389],
              [-86.80605800006222, 36.14733499995285],
              [-86.806471, 36.147928],
              [-86.80836699994975, 36.14697700000941],
              [-86.80795499999999, 36.146389]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-86.803842, 36.143921999999996],
              [-86.803761, 36.144005],
              [-86.80374600001942, 36.1441770000485],
              [-86.804918, 36.1458],
              [-86.805436, 36.145536],
              [-86.80621699999999, 36.146585],
              [-86.80755499999131, 36.145895000035935],
              [-86.807208, 36.145385999999995],
              [-86.806328, 36.144205],
              [-86.803842, 36.143921999999996]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }, {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: "MultiPolygon",
        coordinates: [
          [
            [
              [-86.82083, 36.148815],
              [-86.820293, 36.149196],
              [-86.819585, 36.148572],
              [-86.819971, 36.148087],
              [-86.82083, 36.148815]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }]
  };
  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonObject);
}

function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
  if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
  } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
  } else {
    geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
      processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: I would up vote your answer if I had enough reputation. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would upvote this, but the addfeature event triggers on multiple features, so you're basically resetting the LatLngBounds constructor each time a feature is added, and therefore you can't extend the bounds through each iteration.

Comment: updated to include all the polygons in the GeoJSON (so works for more than the last polygon)

Answer (score 4):

See my answer here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42127338/1628461

The recursive processing function suggested above is clever but there is no need to handle the various `Geometry` types manually.

The Maps API (at least as of V3.26 today) supports `Data.Geometry.prototype.forEachLatLng()` which abstracts away the various `Geometry` types.

Given that you have already imported your geoJSON into `map.data`, it is easy to rezoom the map to fit ("fit-to-bounds"):

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
map.data.forEach(function(feature){
  feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng){
     bounds.extend(latlng);
  });
});

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

If your features are already being iterated for another reason (e.g. setting styles), you can work this code into your existing loop for efficiency.

Comment: Couple typos (line 1: LatLngBounds, line 8: bounds) but aside from that, works beautifully! I've been using the recursive snippet for a while and this is much, much friendlier.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thakns! Typos fixed as suggested.

Comment: best answer here!

Answer (score 0):

@geocodezip's answer doesn't work for me. As the `addfeature` event will trigger for every feature in the JSON. What the this answer shows us is that it will reset the `LatLngBounds()` instance, therefore resetting the extension of the bounding box.

I am doing this using an additional javascript library called [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) (very very handy library btw), which supplies a geo class that can read through GeoJSON and generate the bounding box coordinates needed for the Google map instance's `fitBounds()` method.

```
myNamespace.getLogs().then(function (resp) {
    var logData = myNamespace.map.data.addGeoJson(resp);
    var jsonBounds = d3.geo.bounds(resp);
    myNamespace.mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds({
        lat: jsonBounds[0][1],
        lng: jsonBounds[0][0]
    }, {
        lat: jsonBounds[1][1],
        lng: jsonBounds[1][0]
    });
    myNamespace.map.fitBounds(myNamespace.mapBounds);
});
```

This produces an array of a pair array items, one for SW and one for NE. For example:

```
Array([Array([sw_lng, sw_lat]), Array([ne_lng, ne_lat])])
```