# There's no getPath() or getPaths() function for polygons in a data layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm creating an array of polygons in Google Maps using the loadGeoJson method. I'm making one of the polygons editable. I want to add a listener when a vertice is edited/added.

If I had used the Polygon class, I could have added the listener `set_at` to its path(s), according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#editable_events):

> The listener must be set on the polygon's path. If the polygon has multiple paths, a listener must be set on each path.

Which means that in the Polygon class it can be done like this:

```
let polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ ...options here ...})
let outerPath = polygon.getPath();
google.maps.event.addListener(outerPath, 'set_at', function() {
  console.log('Vertex moved on outer path.');
});
```

However, when the polygons are loaded using loadGeoJson, they are considered as features in the Data layer, but [the Data.Feature class does not have a getPath method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Feature). How can I add the `set_at` listener to a Polygon in the Data.Feature class?

The geojson that is being loaded looks like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Test zone"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[28.29,70.46],[28.34,70.45],[28.37,70.47]]]},"id":"10"}]}
```

Comment: The Geometry` of the `Feature` has a [`forEachLatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Geometry) method that will get the coordinates of the particular geometry.

Comment: Related question (gets the coordinates of all the features in the layer creates a bounds with that, then zooms to the bounds): [Zoom On Google Maps Data Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615267/zoom-on-google-maps-data-layer)

Comment: I'm already creating the bounds using the forEachLatLng():
            
    e.feature.getGeometry().getArray().forEach(function (path) {
       path.getArray().forEach(function (latLng) {
          bounds.extend(latLng);
       }
    })

I've already tried attaching the listener to each path, but it didn't work. Are you saying that I should attach it to each latLng instead?

Comment: A Data.Polygon is different from a google.maps.Polygon, it has different methods to get the geographic data.  There are questions here that contain examples of how to create a google.maps.Polygon from the information in the DataLayer.  If  you want to make them editable, and add listeners to the paths, that is probably what you will have to do.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I find it strange that it's possible to make the Data.Polygon editable, and yet there's no native method to listen for the edits. I temporarily made my Data object global in order to extract the edited geojson in the console, and that worked fine. But to do the same in my .js I would have to make the object permanently global. It's possible, but it feels hacky. I'll try converting to a google.maps.Polygon tomorrow, thanks!