# Zoom to geojson visible polygons with Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am combining and visualizing multiple data sources based on the example available in the developers.google.com website and it's working fine for displaying a full state, you can see the [result here](http://www.force-t.fr/geojson/test2.php?coordination_id=1).

Now, I need to display sub-part of state and so I need centering and zooming on the visible polygons and not on all the polygons.

You can see my test [here](http://www.force-t.fr/geojson/test2.php?secteur_id=1)
As you will see, the map is not centered properly!

I am using the following code :

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
  processPoints(e.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});

function processPoints(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
  if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
  } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
    callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
  } else {
    geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
      processPoints(g, callback, thisArg);
    });
  }
}
```

I probably needs to update the processPoints function, but I don't know what to do...

Comment: Solution given in this similar SO post - [zoom to geojson polygons bounds in Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507044/zoom-to-geojson-polygons-bounds-in-google-maps-api-v3) might help.

Comment: The post is explaining how to zoo an ALL feature while I am trying to zoom only on visible polygons.
So it doesn't help :-(